# Config file value "web_port": what's its usage?

Tags: tezos-client, config

I recently saw that [config file can contain](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/lib_client_base_unix/client_config.ml) `web_port` (default value is `8080`).

I can't find any guide regarding that value. What's its usage?

Answer (score 1):

This is a deprecated parameter. You should be using `--endpoint`. It's the default port that tezos-client uses when connecting to an RPC.